# Keyboard shortcuts for navigating posts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, feedly

Is there a way to navigate my posts (next, previous, minimize, etc.) in Feedly via shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Feedly has loaded, enter the "?" character. That will bring up a list of shortcut commands available.

It's still a "hidden feature", hopefully they'll have that more visible in a future release.